# Can this be considered as an operation over a quotient ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

**NOTE:** The question is inspired by an [operation in cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns). But I try to recast it as a purely algebraic question.

Let $b(x)=b_{3}x^{3}+b_{2}x^{2}+b_{1}x+b_{0}$ be a polynomial whose coefficients are elements of $GF(2^8)$, and consider a fixed polynomial $a(x)=3x^{3}+x^{2}+x+2$. Define the multiplication between $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, denoted $d(x) = a(x) \otimes c(x)$ as their "ordinary" multiplication, modulo $x^4 + 1$.

**EDIT:** By "ordinary" multiplication, I mean $s(x) = a(x) \times c(x)$:

$$a(x)=a_3x^{3}+a_2x^{2}+a_1x+a_0\\
b(x)=b_{3}x^{3}+b_{2}x^{2}+b_{1}x+b_{0}\\
s(x) = s_6x^6 + \dots + s_0 \,,
$$
where $s_i = \sum_{j=0}^i a_i \times b_{i-j}$ is computed over $GF(2^8)$: That is, the addition and multiplication of coefficients are the addition and multiplication of $GF(2^8)$. Finally, we set $d(x) = s(x) \bmod (x^4+1)$.

> Can we say that this operation takes place over the quotient ring $R = GF(2^8)[x]/\langle x^4+1 \rangle$?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "ordinary", but that seems likely. Assuming you have a way of interpreting the coefficients of $a(x)$ as elements of $GF(256)$. For people with math background $2=1+1$. Always. But in $GF(256)$ we have $1+1=0$ and in programmer's notation $2$ is something else (a fixed root of a defining polynomial of that field).

Comment: Oh. I just noticed that you mention "the multiplicative group of $GF(256)[x]/\langle x^4+1\rangle$." That feels a bit strange. After all, you didn't specify that $b(x)$ should come from the multiplicative group. The multiplicative group of $R$ is the group of its units. And the coset of $b(x)$ in $R$ is a unit if and only if $b(1)\neq0$. The generator of the ideal $$x^4+1=(x+1)^4.$$ So the coset of $b(x)$ is invertible, iff $\gcd(b(x),x+1)=1$, iff $b(1)\neq0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks for the helpful comments. I clarified the "ordinary" multiplication, and removed the "multiplicative group" from my question as it was wrong. One thing that made me suspicious is the definition of $R$ itself. I tried entering it into Sage software, but for some reason, it equates $\langle x^4+1 \rangle$ with the principal ideal $\langle 1 \rangle$. I haven't previously seen a ring where the underlying field is neither prime nor infinite.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by $``$a ring where the underlying field is neither prime nor infinite$"$. What I know is that $R$ is a ring which is not an integral domain since $(x^2 + 1)^2 \equiv x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 \equiv x^4 + 1 \equiv 0 \bmod \langle x^4 + 1 \rangle$. So some nonzero element in $R$ has no multiplicative inverse. Also, $R$ is finite since all elements cannot have degree $> 4$ and since the coefficients come from a finite field, there can be only finitely many choices.

Comment: @AlexVong: The ring $GF(2)[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ is defined over the underlying finite field $GF(2)$ (perhaps I should call it the base field?). The ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ is defined over the underlying finite field $\mathbb{R}$. The former case is a prime finite field, the latter is an infinite field. In my studies, I haven't come up with a case where the base field is a non-prime finite field. Do you have an example of such rings (perhaps in a book as a reference)?

Comment: @M.S.Dousti I think the polynomial ring construction works for any commutative ring with $1$. In particular, $GF(p^n)[x]$ is well-defined. Moreover,  one can always quotient a ring by an ideal to get a ring, so $GF(p^n)[x] / \langle f(x) \rangle$ is also well-defined. Now all finite field are of the form $GF(p^n)$, so any example you are looking for must be of the form $GF(p^n)[x] / \langle f(x) \rangle$ where $n > 1$ (so that it is not over a prime field). For reference, perhaps [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/finitefields.pdf) will be useful?

Comment: @M.S.Dousti I'm afraid I don't use Sage. But a possibility that occurs to me is the following. I'm not sure but in Sage you probably first had to define $GF(256)$ as a quotient ring of $GF(2)[x]$ modulo the principal ideal of some degree eight polynomial $p(x)$. It stands to reason that this definition freezes the variable $x$ in the sense that you cannot use it as a free variable in the same context that you use the freshly defined $GF(256)$. I would try and use $t$ (or any other variable) in either the definition of $GF(256)$ or in the definition of $R$.

Comment: Whenever I post an answer about finite fields where this distinction is important I usually reserve a "constant" symbol like $\alpha$ to denote for example a fixed zero of the polynomial $p(x)=x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ in the field $GF(256)$. After all for the purposes of the ring $GF(256)[x]$ that element $\alpha$ **is** a constant, and that "fresh" occurrence of $x$ is unrelated to the polynomial $p(x)$. Much the same way that you can define the field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ as $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$ essentially equating $x=\sqrt2$, and then discuss polynomials like $x^2+(3+\sqrt2)x+1$.

Comment: If this was all clear to you, then I apologize. I have just seen many smart people not appreciating these subtleties. Simply because their education was lacking and they did not know about the details.

Comment: Basically I suspect that your definition of $GF(256)$ turned $x$ into a constant element of that field. Consequently $x^4+1$ is also a constant of that field. And $GF(256)[x]$ is the same object as $GF(256)$ because $x$ is already there.

Comment: Although, the polynomial $x^4+1$ is not irreducible over $GF(2^8)$, there are two reasons that this polynomial is used in AES. First: we have
 $$x^i\quad \mbox{mod}\quad (x^4+1)=x^{(i\,\, \mbox{mod}\,\, 4)}$$
Second: The polynomial $a(x)=\{03\}x^3+\{01\}x^2+\{01\}x+\{02\}$, is irreducible over $x^4+1$.

Comment: I suggest to post you question in [crypto forum](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks a lot for your clear explanations. I tried [asking the question on Sage forum](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/40189/defining-aes-mixcolumns-in-sage/). From what I got, it seems that unfortunately there's no way to ask Sage not to turn $x^4 + 1$ into a "constant", as you described. I'm awaiting further confirmation from the Sage community. Meanwhile, I tried Singular, yet I couldn't figure it out either :(